# Synchronizing threads in JMeter in middle of test

Tags: jmeter, synchronization, beanshell

How to synchronize thread in JMeter? I'd like to have all threads to log in the web application (with a ramp up), then wait and do the loop "compute all" at same time.

If I use the `Synchronizing Timer` (with a timeout > 0), then the 50 threads are synchronized at every step.

How to make them reach the `POST - click on company` and then wait?

I could do some BeanShell timer to wait for a given date (but I'm no BeanShell expert). Is there any way to do that in a more JMeter way?

[image]

Comment: have you tried adding the Synchronizing Timer as a child of the first request in your loop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's explained in the [help](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#timers):

> To apply a timer to a single sampler, add the timer as a child element of the sampler. The timer will be applied before the sampler is executed. To apply a timer after a sampler, either add it to the next sampler, or add it as the child of a Test Action Sampler.

So to apply synchronization at `POST - click on company`, you need to put Synchronizing timer **under** `POST - click on company`. That way all threads will **start** `POST - click on company` at the same time:

```
POST - click on company <-- all threads will synch up here
  |-Synchronizing timer
Loop - computer all
```

If you rather want them to run `POST - click on company` unsynchronized, and synchronize **just before the loop**, then add `Test Action Sampler` after `POST - click on company`, and put Synchronizing timer under it:

```
POST - click on company
Test Action Sampler
  |-Synchronizing timer
Loop - computer all <-- all threads will synch up before loop
```